# Question about written proof for geometric summation

Tags: summation, proof-writing

Suppose $\alpha$ $\ne$ $\beta$ $\in \{0, 2\}^\mathbb{N}$
Prove that $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty\frac{\alpha(k)}{3^k} \ne \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty\frac{\beta(k)}{3^k}. $$

This is the written proof I found online:

Let $x$ be the first sum, and let $y$ be the second. Let $m$ be the smallest integer such that $\alpha_m \ne \beta_m$. (This is the start you suggested.)

Without loss of generality we may assume that $\alpha_m=0$ and $\beta_m=2$. Let $w=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\alpha_i}{3^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\beta_i}{3^i}$. 
Then 
$$x\le w +\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^i}=w+\frac{1}{3^m},$$
and 
$$y\ge w+\frac{2}{3^m},$$
and therefore $x\lt y$.

---

I am having trouble understanding the logic from the "Then x $x\le w +\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^i}=w+\frac{1}{3^m},$" How does the logic work for this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum $w$ covers the first $m$ terms, where the two sums agree.  What is left over is the sum from the $m$th term on.  We have $\alpha_m = 0$ so we can write 
$$x = w + \sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{\alpha(i)}{3^i}$$
But of course since $\alpha(i)$ is either $0$ or $2$, $\alpha(i) \leq 2$

$$x \leq w + \sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^i}$$
The infinite part of the right hand side is a geometric series.

On the other hand, 
$$y = w + \frac{\beta(m)}{3^m}+ \sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{\beta(i)}{3^i}$$
By assumption $\beta(m) = 2$ and the worst case scenario is that all future $\beta$ are $0$, so
$$y \geq w + \frac{2}{3^m} + 0$$

Does this address your question?